# How to ensure atomicity when updating a field in a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to write a piece of code such that it is *guaranteed* that at any one time, only one process can update a field for a certain record in the posts table.

Is this the correct way to do it?

```
#Make a check before entering transaction, so that a transaction
#is not entered into needlessly (this check is just for avoiding
#using DB resources that will be used when starting a transaction)    

if @post.can_set_to_active?

  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do

    #Make a check again, this time after entering transaction, to be 
    #sure that post can be marked active.

    #Expectation is that inside a transaction, it is guaranteed that no other
    #process can set the status of this post.

    if @post.can_set_to_active?
      #now set the post to active
      @post.status = :active
      @post.save
    end #end of check inside transaction

  end #end of transaction

end #end of check outside transaction
```

Also, is there some way to *test* this scenario using RSpec or even some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Post

  @@activation_lock = Mutex.new

  def activate
    self.status = :active
    self.save
  end
  synchronize :activate, :with => :@@activation_lock

end
```